# creating dynamic navigation in zf3

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I am using zend framework3 in my project. I am able to create static navigation by following the docs [link](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/navigation/)

Now I have to fetch the menu data from database then create the navigation.
For this i am using i have provide the configuration into the module.config.php which is config file of the album module.

```
  <?php
  namespace Album;

  use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
  use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
  use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;
  use Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory;
  use Album\Navigation\AlbumNavigationFactory;

  return [
    'controllers' => [
      'factories' => [
         Controller\AlbumController::class => Factory\AlbumControllerFactory::class,
        Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
          ],
       ],

     // Add this section:
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
           'navigation' => Navigation\AlbumNavigationFactory::class,
            Model\AlbumTable::class => Factory\AlbumTableFactory::class,
         ],
       ],
     // The following section is new and should be added to your file:
     'router' => [
        'routes' => [
        'album' => [
            'type'    => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/album[/:action[/:id]]',
                'constraints' => [
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ],
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\AlbumController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'index' => [
            'type'    => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/index[/:action[/:id]]',
                'constraints' => [
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ],
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
              ],
            ],
         ],
      ],

     'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
          'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
       ],
    ],
  ];
```

In zend framework2 we simple pass a navigation key with factory class as

```
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Navigation' => 'Album\Navigation\AlbumNavigationFactory'
         ),
    );
```

In zend framework3 i am doing the same thing as below

```
    'service_manager' => [
       'factories' => [
         'navigation' => Navigation\AlbumNavigationFactory::class,
          Model\AlbumTable::class => Factory\AlbumTableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
```

I am using Navigation\AlbumNavigationFactory::class to call factory for fetching the data.
but i am not be able to get the navigation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

here is part of my code. I think will help. Work perfect.

In Module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig()
 { 
    return array( 
      'factories' => array(
          'ItemsFromDatabase::class => Navigation\BlogNavigationFactory::class,
       )
            );
}

public function getViewHelperConfig() {  
      return[
        'factories' => [
            'AddItemsInNavigation' => function($helpers) {
               $navigation = $helpers->get('Application')->getServiceManager()->get('Zend\Navigation\Default')->findOneByLabel('Blog');
               $newItems = $helpers->get(ItemsFromDatabase::class);
             return new View\Helper\AddItemsInNavigation($navigation, $newItems);    
                    },

                ],
```

Blog\View\Helper\AddItemsInNavigation.php

```
<?php
namespace Blog\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class AddItemsInNavigation extends AbstractHelper {

protected $navigation;
protected $newItems;

public function __construct($navigation, $newItems) {
    $this->navigation = $navigation;
    $this->newItems = $newItems; 
}

public function addItems() {
   return $this->navigation->addPages($this->newItems);

}

}
```

In layout

```
      <?php
      $this->AddItemsInNavigation()->addItems(); //plugin

      $nawDef = $this->navigation('Zend\Navigation\Default')->menu();

      echo $nawDef->setMinDepth(0)->setMaxDepth(4)->setUlClass('nav navbar-nav');

                ?>
```

W  Blog\Navigation\BlogNavigationFactory.php

```
<?php
namespace Blog\Navigation;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\Navigation\Navigation;
use Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory;

class BlogNavigationFactory extends DefaultNavigationFactory {

protected $pages;

public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null) {
    return new Navigation($this->getPages($container));
}

protected function getPages(ContainerInterface $container) {

    $navigation = array();

    if (null === $this->pages) {

        $navigation[] = array ( //for exemple 
            'label' => 'Jaapsblog.nl',
            'uri'   => 'http://www.jaapsblog.nl'
        );

        $mvcEvent = $container->get('Application')
                ->getMvcEvent();

        $routeMatch = $mvcEvent->getRouteMatch();
        $router = $mvcEvent->getRouter();
        $pages = $this->getPagesFromConfig($navigation);

        $this->pages = $this->injectComponents(
                $pages, $routeMatch, $router
        );
    }

    return $this->pages;
}

}
```

Comment: thanks for comment. after implementing the above code i am getting an exeception "Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Unable to resolve service "Zend\Navigation\Default" to a factory;" Do you have any idea of this?

Comment: Zend\Navigation\Default - is the name of my navigation. You find this in module.config.php file. for example:      
    'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(

Comment: Could you provide that one? It will be very helpful to me, Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide more details 'navigation' => array( 'default' => array('

Answer (score 1):

cd.

In module.config.php

```
'navigation' => array(
'default' => array(  

    'blog' => array(
            'label' => 'Blog',
            'route' => 'blog-front',
            'controller' => 'blog',
            'action' => 'index',
        )
  )
)
```

Comment: i have added the above code snippet in to the module.config.php files. But i am getting Class 'Album\view\Helper\AddItemsInNavigation'  not found error in Module.php file while the class is exists into the respective directory. Do you have any idea?

Comment: class AddItemsInNavigation.php this is helper.

I wrote how to should look class AddItemsInNavigation.php
As I see You create diffrent project than my. You should change in AddItemsInNavigation.php namespace Blog\View\Helper;  on namespace  Album\View\Helper;

Comment: I have checked that that is correct in AddItemsInNavigation (namespace Album\view\Helper;).I have just changed View to view folder but doing as per your suggestion it is also not working. I don't know the reason of class not found as i was able to call the same way in ZF2.

Comment: I have moved the Helper folder under the src folder then its working. I don't know why it is not finding the class inside the view folder. Thanks for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's that are you looking for, but i recommend to take a look on this page:

https://github.com/fabiopaiva/zf2-navigation-bootstrap3

Comment: @Andry Bueno I have checked the provided URL. My question is the array which we are passing in navigation key as 
'navigation' => array(
    'default' => array(array(
            'label' => 'Home',
            'route' => 'home',
            'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-home'
        ),
I want this array from the database. Do you have any idea how can i get this array from database?